# Who's managing the memory when an external program calls `Rf_allocXXX` via R's C API interface?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm writing an R package in Rust, which communicates with R via its C API interface.

One fundamental question seems tricky to me is the memory management.

So first let me briefly explain how my Rust program communicates with R.

---

First, on R side, it calls a C dynamic library with `.Call()`. The C library then is linked to the Rust static library with C compatible ABI.

R scripts is doing some simple works like input validation, and decide which C function to call based on inputs. Then C program passes the calls to underlying Rust functions, which are exposed as C-compatible functions.

It's pretty clear so far, then it gets tricky once Rust has finished computation and needs to send result back.

---

One option is to directly call `Rf_allocXXX` functions on Rust side, and store results within it. Then passes the raw pointer of the R object back to C, and then to R.

But it's unclear to me, whether this will result in ***memory leak***.

It seems to me that if Rust calls `Rf_allocXXX`, the new R objected (`SEXP`) is created on Rust program's heap memory. When passing the raw pointer out, Rust will not destroy the object. But then what will happen?

Note that the `SEXP` created by Rust in this way is directly passed back to C and R. There's no re-allocation. So it seems very unclear to me whether this `SEXP` would be correctly freed by R's GC.

---

A related question,

What I noticed from `Rcpp`'s source code is, it seems like just calling R's C API for creating its various vectors, which are wrappers of `SEXP`.

But I'm not yet clear how it deal with memory management. Does it just simply turns the `SEXP` object back and R will correctly handle GC?

Answer (score 5):

It's all (as always) in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) (and as always not the easiest to find....)

In a nutshell, when you call an R extension package are you essentially required to call R's API and its `Calloc()` and `Free()` routines (and variants). Why?  Because *anything* you return to R becomes an R object and is indistinguishable from all other R object and behaves identical.  Including, very importantly, when it comes to garbage collection.

And the only way to do that is via R's own allocator.  So Rcpp uses it.  And creates objects that are in fact indistinguishable.  Which makes it all work.

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction("IntegerVector foo() { 
+                           IntegerVector v = {1, 2, 3}; return v; }") 
R> foo()
[1] 1 2 3 
R> identical(foo(), c(1L, 2L, 3L))  
[1] TRUE  
R> identical(foo(), 1:3)    
[1] TRUE    
R>
```

But as a first step, you could just do your thing in Rust to compute results, and then pay the one-time conversion cost (from your object into the `SEXP` R expects as a result of a `.Call()`) .  "Walk before you run" and all that.  Rust bindings would be cool.  I presume you know Jeroen and others had already done some work?

Comment: Yes I've found Jeroen's presentation and the [example packages](https://github.com/r-rust).
My current implementation is just to compute the intermediate result and send then to C wrapper function as generic C structs or primitive types, and let C re-pack these C types to `SEXP`. But it'd be even better if I can directly create `SEXP` in Rust.

Comment: I have the concern of memory leak, because in general it's advised that
*whoever allocated the memory is responsible to free it*.
For example if I created a vector in Rust and sends its pointer and length to C, then normally I need to destroy the vector via a callback function.
But this gets unclear as R has its own Garbage Collector.

Comment: It does. And there is memory profiling, see (again) Writing R Extensions. Also CRAN is *extremely* diligent and runs valgrind on all packages, SAN/UBSAN, analysis and much more.  "Despite what people may think" (based on first glances) this is not a hokey bunch of amateur code.  It's solid.

Answer (score 2):

Update to this question:

Based on [Dirik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014219/5715571) and after reading [Memory Allocation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Memory-allocation) section in `Writing R Extensions`, now I realised that

- If a foreign program, potentially in other languages,  created a `SEXP`
  object via `R_allocXXX` interface or the equivalence in `Rcpp`, then R
  is responsible to free the memory,

  - At the end of the call of `.C()`, `.Call()`, and `.External()`
  - Or when an error is raised
- But if an R object is manually created via `malloc` or similar
  interface, user is responsible to free the memory, regardless of
  whether this object is created in C, `Rcpp`, or other foreign programs.

So if we assume R doesn't panic before freeing the memory, then in most
cases we should use `R_allocXXX` bindings to create `SEXP`, and there
will be ***NO MEMORY LEAK***. Once the object is turned to R, it's safe.

But still caution must be made when dealing with Foreign Function Interface (FFI) in general,

- If we manually allocate the memory and returns a C object to C interface, then
  we need to make sure neither side of FFI panics before converting the C object
  to `SEXP`. Otherwise the memory is not freed.
- Similarly this applies to when we manually allocated the memory in C program,
  and sends an object to a foreign program
- In any cases, manually allocated memory needs to be manually freed.

So in general, whenever possible, we should use `R_allocXXX` interface for memory safety.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get to that part of your question. And "yes of course" -- in C++ (with or without Rcpp) we use the STL all day long and it has its allocators.  And modern languages manage that: once you're out of scope all is well.  _You just can't use those 'native' allocators for things you return to R._

Comment: Well in Rust normally values are dropped when they are out of scope.
Actually if a value, not its reference, is passed to another function, it will be unusable except for those who can be cheaply copied, like primitive types. But if an object is given out to C FFI, it won't be dropped. So either the other side of FFI drops it, or it should be passed back to Rust to be dropped. But both of them have to be done manually.